# Netbeans - php is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, composer-php

I'm trying to run Composer -> install (no-dev) with Netbeans IDE 7.4 but i get the following error:

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                         
  Error Output: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  
  operable program or batch file.
```

I already put php.exe path on Netbeans.

Comment: Maybe you should try adding the php.exe to the PATH environment variable for the OS.

Comment: What are you mean? I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: For an application to appear on the console cmd.exe and can be used system wide you have to add them on the PATH variable, a quick google will show you how...

Comment: Same issue. php.exe exists on PATH. Successfully able to run `composer install` in CLI from the project directory.